# Add data from the registration page to firebase database along with signing the user

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, registration

mainActivity.java

```
public class Signup extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText name, mobile_no, mail, passwd, cnfpasswd;
    Button signup;
    TextView login_up;
    FirebaseAuth user;
    DatabaseReference userdetails;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        mobile_no = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mobile_no);
        mail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email_addr);
        passwd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwd);
        cnfpasswd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.confpasswd);

        userdetails = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User");


        user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        signup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signup_button);

        login_up = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Loginpage_text);

        signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                validate();
                add();



            }
        });

        login_up.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }


    public void add() {
        final String Email = mail.getText().toString().trim();
        final String Passwd = passwd.getText().toString().trim();
        final String mobileno = mobile_no.getText().toString().trim();
        final String Name = name.getText().toString().trim();
        final String Cnfpasswd = cnfpasswd.getText().toString().trim();


        userDetails userInformation = new userDetails(Email, Passwd, mobileno, Name, Cnfpasswd);
        Toast.makeText(this, "information saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        userdetails.setValue(userInformation);
        Toast.makeText(this, "data succeefully added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }




    public void validate() {
        final String Email = mail.getText().toString().trim();
        final String Passwd = passwd.getText().toString().trim();
        final String mobileno = mobile_no.getText().toString().trim();
        final String Name = name.getText().toString().trim();
        final String Cnfpasswd = cnfpasswd.getText().toString().trim();


        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(Email)) {

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(Passwd)) {

                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(mobileno)) {

                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(Name)) {

                        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(Cnfpasswd)) {

                            user.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(Email, Passwd)
                                    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                Intent intent = new Intent(Signup.this, LoginActivity.class);
                                                intent.putExtra("NAME", Email);
                                                intent.putExtra("PASSWORD", Passwd);
                                                startActivity(intent);
                                                Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "registered successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                                            } else {
                                                Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "registeration unsuccessful ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                    }
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

userDetails.java

```
public class userDetails
{
    public  String Id;
    public String Name_user;
    public String email_user;
    public String passwd_user;
    public String cnfpasswd_user;
    public String number_user;




    public userDetails(String Id,String Name_user, String email_user, String passwd_user, String cnfpasswd_user, String number_user) {
        this.Id = Id;
        this.Name_user = Name_user;
        this.email_user = email_user;
        this.passwd_user = passwd_user;
        this.cnfpasswd_user = cnfpasswd_user;
        this.number_user = number_user;
    }

    public String getName_user() {
        return Name_user;
    }

    public String getEmail_user() {
        return email_user;
    }

    public String getPasswd_user() {
        return passwd_user;
    }

    public String getCnfpasswd_user() {
        return cnfpasswd_user;
    }

    public String getNumber_user() {
        return number_user;
    }
}
```

I am trying to add data to my firebase database, but when I click the signup button
nothing happens. But when I use only the validate class it registers the user.

The problem is with the with add class which I am using to add data to firebase database.

Comment: do you invoke `Toast` message?

Comment: nope,nothing happens i get redirected to to the start page

Comment: try this tutorial may be help you :https://www.androidhive.info/2016/06/android-getting-started-firebase-simple-login-registration-auth/

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake. Call add(); method inside the success response of sign up like shown below. because add() method will call before the signu completes it this code.

```
 user.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(Email, Passwd)
                            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                        add();
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(Signup.this, LoginActivity.class);
                                        intent.putExtra("NAME", Email);
                                        intent.putExtra("PASSWORD", Passwd);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                        Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "registered successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "registeration unsuccessful ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    }
                                }
                            });
```

And also if it didnt work, use HashMap to push data to firebase as shown below.

```
      public void add() {
       final String Email = mail.getText().toString().trim();
       final String Passwd = passwd.getText().toString().trim();
       final String mobileno = mobile_no.getText().toString().trim();
       final String Name = name.getText().toString().trim();
       final String Cnfpasswd = cnfpasswd.getText().toString().trim();

      HashMap<String, Object> userMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
      userMap.put("email",Email);
      userMap.put("password",passwd);

     userdetails.setValue(userMap);
     Toast.makeText(this, "data succeefully added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   }
```